# Why are my added NewIssues not transfered to sonar? (Custom Sonar Plugin)

Tags: sonarqube, kotlin, sonar-plugin

Heyho,

I have my sonar-kotlin-plugin up and running. My RuleDefinitions are dislayed on the Rules-page, but when analyzing some kotlin projects the found issues are not saved.

My sensor-issue-adding-code looks like this:

```
private fun projectIssues(detektion: Detektion, context: SensorContext) {
    val fileSystem = context.fileSystem()
    val baseDir = fileSystem.baseDir()
    val predicates = fileSystem.predicates()
    detektion.findings.forEach { _, findings ->
        findings.forEach { issue ->
            val inputFile = fileSystem.inputFile(predicates.`is`(baseDir.resolve(issue.location.file)))
            if (inputFile != null) {
                val newIssue = context.newIssue()
                        .forRule(findKey(issue.id))
                        .gap(2.0) // TODO what to write here?
                        .primaryLocation(issue, inputFile)
                println(newIssue)
                newIssue.save()
            } else {
                println("No file found for ${issue.location.file}")
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun NewIssue.primaryLocation(issue: Finding, inputFile: InputFile): NewIssue {
    val (line, _) = issue.startPosition
    val newIssueLocation = newLocation()
            .on(inputFile)
            .at(inputFile.selectLine(line))
            .message("TODO needs PR!")
    return this.at(newIssueLocation)
}
```

Even the `println(newIssue)` shows that it was created.

I use `sonar-plugin-api version 5.6`, `org.sonar-gradle-plugin in version 2.5`, my sonar distribution is in version `5.6.6` and I use the `embedded database`.

My whole code is in this PR `https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt/pull/81`.

Thx for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my issue by activating my rules in the RulesProfile:

```
override fun createProfile(validation: ValidationMessages): RulesProfile {
    val profile = RulesProfile.create(DETEKT_WAY, KOTLIN_KEY)
    RULE_KEYS.forEach {
        profile.activateRule(Rule.create(it.repository(), it.rule()), null)
    }
    return profile
}
```